# Django Not Sending Tasks to Celery in Production

Tags: python, django, server, celery, gunicorn

I am a deployer and delpoys django applications using gunicorn & nginx. Recently, I setup a celery project and here are my services:
*Gunicorn Project Service*

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for my project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/project.sock project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*Celery Service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Worker Service for my project
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myenv/bin/celery -A project worker -l info

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Celery Logs are stuck at: celery@server ready. But When I run `python3 manage.py runserver` in production celery logs updates & my task works but not when I use direct service...

I tried changing celery to solo `worker --pool=solo -l info` [celery service] but that didn't work.
My Server RAM & CPU is not being fuly utilized so that's not an issue.

Thank You!